# JBoss AS 7 CLI no se puede conectar

Tags: jboss, jboss-as-7

Estaba pensando hacer algunas configuraciones a mi `Jboss AS 7.1.1` así que inicié el servidor mediante el comando:

```
C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin\standalone.bat -b 0.0.0.0
```

e inició sin problemas.

Intenté conectarme a la interfaz de línea de comandos `jboss-cli.exe` con el comando

```
C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin\jboss-cli.bat
```

me marca

> JAVA_HOME is not set. Unexpected results may occur.
>   Set JAVA_HOME to the directory of your local JDK to avoid this message.
>   You are disconnected at the moment. Type 'connect' to connect to the server or 'help' for the list of supported commands.
>   [disconnected /]

Así que proceddo a intentar el comando

```
connect
```

Y obtengo el siguiente mensaje

> The controller is not available at localhost:9999

También ya lo corrí como administrador pero no tuve éxito.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Lo resolví finalmente agregando dos nuevos parámetros a la forma en que corro mi servidor en el [sts](/questions/tagged/sts), en concreto `Djboss.bind.address.management` apuntando a mi *localhost* y `Djboss.management.native.port` apuntando al puerto que mencionaba el error; quedando los argumentos de programa del servidor de la sigiente manera:

```
-mp "C:/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/modules" -jaxpmodule javax.xml.jaxp-provider org.jboss.as.standalone -b localhost --server-config=standalone.xml -Djboss.server.base.dir=C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone -b 0.0.0.0 -Djboss.bind.address.management=127.0.0.1 -Djboss.management.native.port=9999
```

Espero en un futuro esta información le pueda servir a alguien.